# C++ Считалка. Проблема с зацикливанием

Tags: c++

Пишу код под задачу со считалкой в строке и одномерным массивом с людьми.
Через поток делю строку на слова и через while выполняю считалку один раз.
А нужно пять раз. Вроде зациклил и написал переменную n,чтобы каждый раз отсчет начинался со следующего человека,но оно не работает,т.е. выводит 5 раз тот же результат. В чем может быть проблема?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sstream>

#include <string>

#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

std::string sch("Эни, бени, рики, таки, Турба, урба, синтибряки, Эус, бэус, краснобэус, Бац!");
std::cout << "Считалочка: " << sch << endl;

int n,j,i;
int people[5];

people[0] = 1;
people[1] = 2;
people[2] = 3;
people[3] = 4;
people[4] = 5;
cout << "Нумерация людей: ";
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%2d", people[i]);
}
cout << endl;

std::stringstream ss(sch);
n = 0;
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    while (!ss.eof())
    {
        std::string s;
        ss >> s;
        i = n;
        while (ss >> s)
        {
            i++;
            if (i > 4)
                i = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << people[i] << endl;
    n++;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читайте свой же код и пытайтесь себе рассказать что написали:

```
while (!ss.eof())
```

Пока не достигли признака конца ввода(когда достигнете, установится failbit)
    {
        std::string s;
        ss >> s;
    вводим из строкового потока строку(кстати std::istringstream обьект вполне достаточно)
        i = n;

```
    while (ss >> s)
```

пока вводим из потока строку.... Это значит, что если все нормально, то вы достигнете конца ввода  после выхода из цикла, поэтому условие внешнего цикла не выполнится и строка будет инициализирована последней строкой из потока. Получается что внешный абсолютно бесполезный

```
    {
        i++;
        if (i > 4)
            i = 0;
    }
```

А  это зачем, если вы потом всеравно пытаетесь инициализировать  значением `n ( i = n; )`
    }

В общем написан бессмысленный код.

**Насколько я понел** вам нужен типа такого:

```
std::istringstream ss(sch);
std::string s;  
for (j = 0; ss >> s; j++)
{           
    if (j > 4)
        j = 0;      
    cout << people[j] << endl;      
}
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Чтобы повторить все это, с началом отсчета от следующего, нужен такой цикл:

```
int j = -1; // чтобы ++j == 0

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    while (ss >> s) ++j;
    // if ( j > 4 ) j = 0; можно заменить на j % 5
    j %= 5;
    cout << people[j] << endl;
    //после цикла нужно  установить gootbit
    ss.clear();
    //и начать читать заново от начала
    ss.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);        
}
```

Или же проще:

```
int n = 0, j = -1;
while (ss >> s) ++n;    
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    j += n;
    // if ( j > 4 ) j = 0; можно заменить на j % 5
    j %= 5;
    cout << people[j] << endl;              
}
```

Comment: В том то и дело. Я пытаюсь написать что-то и получилось это. Я учусь.
Спасибо,что указали на то,что неверно. Можете подсказать,как это исправить и сделать со смыслом эту часть?

Comment: Я не смогу помочь, поскольку пока я не понел чего вы хотите получать, какова ваша цель?

Comment: С помощью считалки в строке выбрать людей из одномерного массива и (в коде это еще не дописано) поочереди внести их в пустую очередь. В начале отсчет ведется от первого человека,в следующем разе уже от следующего за ним. И так внести всех 5 человек.

Comment: Я добавил как выводить элементы с помощью считальки

Comment: Да,что-то вроде того. Только нужно чтобы выводился только последний элемент,то есть,на котором считалка кончилась.
И это повторилось 5 раз и при этом место начала отсчета двигалось на одного человека вперед после каждого раза.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Попробую сейчас сам еще доработать,если вы не захотите еще немного помочь.
Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Как сделать так,чтобы в этом цикле в конце выводилось только последнее значение? То есть значение, на котором считалка кончилась.

Comment: Почитайте обновление еще раз

Comment: Прикрутил очередь и доработал окончательно. Спасибо огромное еще раз за помощь.